# Navigation graph has not been set for NavController

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I have 2 activities.

Main activity, let's call `A` has the navigation controller setup with Compose. The navigation controller works fine and it uses the same everywhere (*No duplicated* `NavHostController`)

I have a button on activity `A` that it launches the activity `B`. After finishing it returns and launches a lambda to call `navController.navigate("foo")`.

It crashes with the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot navigate to NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/foo }. Navigation graph has not been set for NavController androidx.navigation.NavHostController@a2ff265.
```

The navigation controller works fine but when coming back from the activity `B` it creates a new `navController` object where the graph hasn't been setup, thus it crashes. I've checked this with the log.

To "*solve*" it I've done the following: Created a `coroutineScope` and then inside the scope navigated `navController.navigate("somewhere")` and it didn't crash. My feeling is that the issue could be related to the race condition.

Is there something that I could be missing? I know that when coming back from the activity the destination route are `null`. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.